# Executing javascript functions in loaded tab in YUI

Tags: javascript, yui

I have a tabset that loads an edit page into a tab on the details page of a user edit.  I create the tabs dynamically and they are loaded from the server when the tab is clicked.

I have javascript code that needs to run when this tab is loaded so that calendar and autocomplete controls are available.

How can I ensure that the javascript existing in the imported html is loaded?  Is this possible to do.

I have tried various events on the tab such as `beforeDataLoadedChange` and `contentChange` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want an event to fire when you click on a tab you can use `activeTabChange` event , check this example http://jsfiddle.net/ekcgd/.

However for an event that gets fired if data or contents inside a tab is loaded you may try using  [loadHandler](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Tab.html#property_loadHandler) which is called when a request to pull your data from server has success or failure.

```
this.loadHandler =  {
            success: function(o) {
                this.set(CONTENT, o.responseText);
            },
            failure: function(o) {
            }
        };
```

modify this default loadHandler to fire a custom event on success and subscribe to that event so that you can run js code that you need .